# I am typing the kql below to list users that succesfsully log-in outside of the U.S

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

**I used != to exclude United States to list all countries that aren't United States but it keeps on showing the U.S. as well. Anybody know how to fix this?** The query I typed is shown below.

SecurityEvent
| where AccountType == "User" and EventID == 4624 and TimeGenerated > ago(1d)

SigninLogs
| where LocationDetails != 'United States' and ResultType == 0

Comment: Hi rk3, please accept the answer, this is the StackOverflow way of saying "thank you" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct.
Maybe for some records the value of LocationDetails is `United States`  (note the space at the end), `United  States` (note the two spaces between the words), `United states` (note the lowercase `s` in `states`) or something like that, and that's why they are not filtered out?

Comment: Yeah you were right. i had to put down US instead of United States. That resolved it. Thanks!